# Асинхронный jsonp ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Добро пожаловать.

Использую библиотеку jquery.min. Пытаюсь отправить асинхронный jsonp(+Long Poll) запрос с одного домена, на другой. Но ничего не получается. Браузер виснет. Всегда отправляется синхронный запрос. И это не смотря на то, что в параметрах я выставляю **async: true**. Отправляю запрос так:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: 'jsonp',
timeout: 30*1000,
cache: false,
async: true,    
contentType: "application/json",
crossDomain: true,
jsonpCallback: 'test_responce',
url: "http://sub.site.ru/test.php",
data: "numb="+1234,
   success: function(data) {
      alert("Запрос выполнен");
   }
});
```

Может ли JSONP работать асинхронно?

Answer (score 1):

Если браузер поддерживает атрибут async для скриптов, то должно выполнятся асинхронно.